# Showing $\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1(u_x^2+2u_y^2+u^2-x^2y^2u)\, dx\, dy\geq c$.

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Prove that for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$:
>   $$G(u) =\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1(u_x^2+2u_y^2+u^2-x^2y^2u)\, dx\, dy\geq c$$
>
> for every $u \in H_0^1$.

I know that

$$G(u) =\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1(u_x^2+2u_y^2+u^2-x^2y^2u)\, dx\, dy\geq \int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1(u_x^2+2u_y^2+u^2-u)\, dx\,dy.$$

But what else do I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$ u^2 -x^2y^2u = \left(u - \frac 12x^2y^2\right)^2 - \frac 14 x^4y^4 $$
Now 
$$ G(u) \ge -\int_{[-1,1]^2} \frac 14x^4y^4 \,d(x,y) \ge -\int_{[-1,1]^2}\frac 14\,d(x,y) = -1 $$